# Exception logging on request with WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, logging, soap

I have a set of web services in my project. All these web services use Nlog for logging into the database, Currently it is logging  all the requests and responses into the database using a class which inherits the `IClientMessageInspector`. Now I need to log only the Request when ever there is an Exception. How can i do that ?

```
public void AfterRecieveReply(ref Message,object correlationState)
{
    _logger.Debug(reply.ToString());
}

public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
{
    _logger.Debug(request.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the server-side code throws an exception, it will get wrapped up into a SOAP fault. In your `AfterReceiveReply` method, the exception will cause the message to have the `IsFault` property set to true.

There's no way to know this is happening in `BeforeSendRequest` since the exception hasn't even happened yet; you'll have to either log every request, or somehow save them for later. One way to do this is to return a new `Guid` from every `BeforeSendRequest` call, and use a `Dictionary<Guid, Message>` to store all requests. You could look up the exception requests later on when the reply indicates a fault has happened.

Comment: Michael can you give me a sample code I am not able to use DIctionary<Guid,Message>

Comment: Hi michael, the technique you told worked, what if there is no response and then it doesnt come to afterrecievereply right....than how can i log the request whenever it doesnt go AfterRecieveReply and whenever the response is lost.

Comment: That will be harder, you would need some kind of timer that checks your dictionary for "lost" requests and logs them. But WCF calls should be blocking, i think you should always get a response even if  its  a timeout, I'm not sure.